# Auto-Implemented Properties on Framework 3.0

Tags: c#, .net

Reading this article I thougth automatic property work on .NET Framework 3.0, but some collegues substain it's not true. Are they correct?

Comment: Was googling too hard? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: They're compiler features rather than .NET framework features. You can use a later compiler and produce .NET 2.0 code that contains such properties.

Comment: @Jon that article tells which version of C# included the feature not which version of .NET that supports the (compiled) code. `.NET != C#` and in reality it's the CLR that determines whether the compiled code is supported or not and the code will run on CLR v2 (shipped with .NET and C# v2)

Comment: @RuneFS: That is irrelevant since .NET 3.0 was introduced alongside C# 3.0, so obviously if C# 3.0 supports it then .NET 3.0 also supports it (which is the question that was asked).

Comment: @Jon C# 3.0 was released alongside .NET 3.5 **not** .NET 3.0. The C# compiler available (v2.0) when .NET 3.0 was released did **not** support auto properties

Comment: @Jon: it doesn't answer to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatically implemented properties don't depend on the *framework* at all. They're simply a part of the *language*. If you're using a compiler which supports C# 3 and higher (and you haven't explicitly set the language version) you'll be fine, even targeting framework 2.0.

See [my article on C# and .NET versions](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx) (which needs updating) for information about using C# 3 features when targeting versions of the framework before 3.5 (the framework version which first came with C# 3).

Comment: Here I found this: 
Some C# 3 features can be used freely in .NET 2.0; [..]; Fully available features; Automatically implemented properties, implicitly typed local variables and arrays, object and collection initializers, anonymous types, partial methods, and lambda expressions can all be used at will.

Comment: @Gik25: Yes, you've quoted my article... I'm not sure of the point of your comment.

Comment: That's really interesting. It was what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Its part of the language and not framework.It was introduced in C# 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported in  C# 3.0 and later versions.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework 3.0 was an extension to the base class library more than anything else. There was no changes to the core languages included.

C# 3.0 was released with .NET 3.5 and included auto properties.

The CLR remained the same for both releases of .NET som any code compiled with the C# 3.0 or 2.0 compiler can run on the same runtime and you can therefor use auto properties when targeting the version 2.0 of the runtime and the v3.0 of the framework as long as the compiler you are using has the particular language feature. Ie C# 3.0+

However if you are using libraries specific to .NET 3.5 and targeting a machine with .NET 3.0 installed you need to make sure that the libraries are available on the machine where you install the application.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is possible in .NET 3.0, as per Habib's link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) - C# 3.0 will by default (and almost always) be used when targetting .NET 3.0, as per Jon's link at http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx.

I agree though, there is no need to ask this on a Q&A site.  You (or anyone) could have found out very easily indeed.

Comment: C# 3.0 isn't the same as .NET 3.0 though. C# 3.0 was released with .NET 3.5. It's a reasonable question - some language features require framework support, and others don't.

Comment: C3 v3 != .NET v3.0 (which was only an extension of the BCL with WCF,WPF and the like)

Comment: Can't tell if mind-numbing pedantry or a focus on completeness.. but, sure, OK, I've indicated that in all but the "corner-est" of cases, C# 3.0 is used when building for .NET 3.0.

Comment: C# v3-0 is usually used to target .NET 3.5 not .NET 3.0. When .NET 3.0 was realeased the newest veersion of C# was v2.0. Autoproperties can be used for .NET 3.0 but _only_ when using a compiler that shipped later than .NET 3.0 (and that's probably the root of the confusion C# 3.0 supports auto-properties but the version of C# available when .NET 3.0 was released does not)

Comment: @KierenJohnstone: The point is that it's a reasonable question - not all C# 3 features work with .NET 3.0, after all.